# 18.04 LTS upgrade (16.04) Failed to reboot

Tags: boot, upgrade, 18.04, reboot, lts

Also entered here: Suspend Issues on Ubuntu 18.04 (and other flavours) – Troubleshooting and Fixes

I've kept my 16.04 lts consistently updated and chose to upgrade today to 18.04 lts.

I followed instructions within 16.04 and was still able to use the computer until it was ready to reboot with 18.04 lts. I was hoping this would work rather than a fresh installation since I wish to keep my files and folders.

After passing the BIOS I had my usual choices of *Ubuntu, Advanced Options and Win 10 (It is a dual boot set up machine). Then white writing on black appeared (see image 1):
2 ACPI errors [CAPD] and another

The dark purple/black screen appeared with 18.04 and the dots. Then came flashing a message, that...Gave up waiting for suspended/ resume d ervice: /dev/sdc1: clean, 467342/16580608 files, 10722236/66302208 blocks   (see image 2)

There is nothing further, it stops flashing. So I switched off and tried Advanced options..

Using the advanced option 4.1.15 0-30 (recovery mode), it failed, but everything ok'd i chose then a normal boot, again all ok'd, except [FAILED]-Failed to start Samba NMB Daemon. See 'systemc1 status nmdb.service' for details. Further down says [OK] started Samba SMB Daemon. (however..) And the PC remains in this mode unbooted at the last entry [OK] Started Update UTMP about system Runlevel 
Changes until turned off

What can I do other than do a fresh install from a DVD? The machine will not boot Ubuntu now.

[image: image one]

[image: image two]

Comment: The writing of the question is rather lengthy and confusing. Try to sharply identify your problem and ask your question. Then include the supporting detail and information you believe might be relevant to solve the question.

Comment: I had been running 16.04 lts and tried to upgraded through Terminal whilst running it. It failed to restart, as pictured above and described.